# Will buffer in sink miss when flink sink failed?

Tags: hbase, apache-flink, sink

I'm using flink to process a lot of data and add into HBase.To improve the speed of sink to hbase, i buffered some data on flink sink operate.When the batch threshold is reached，the data will send to HBase.

But if the sink operate failed before the batch threshold is reached,
will data on the buffer miss?If i send data one by one to HBase,the speed seems too slow.

Has anybody got any pointers on how best to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Data in buffer will be lost when sink task failed.

This situation cannot be saved if you don't use checkpoint.

By using checkpoint, you can restart the program from checkpoint and the data will be sent into HBase again with semantics of at-least-once. To achieve semantics of exactly-once, you can try implementing CheckpointListener and commit the buffer when checkpoint is completed.

Comment: Thanks!But according to the definition of checkpoint,checkpoint olny save the status of operates.If restart the program from checkpoint and the buffer data will be sent again , does it mean the checkpoint will also save the buffer data?Or the checkpoint just save  the sink status, and repaly all the buffer data from upstream? I think it cost too much,if the buffer is 5M or bigger such as, about thousands data will be replayed.

Comment: @manyu1026   Assuming that you're using kafka as the source, the checkpoint will save kafka's offset in kakfa operator's state. The data will be replayed from kafka after you recover the job.